# Why「で／に」cannot be omitted ? (どこかで　/　どこかに)

Tags: grammar, particles

The particle「へ／を」, can be omitted after「どこか　or　なにか」.

But, with「で／に」we can't. Why?

> どこかに電話がありますか。／　どこか（へ）逃避行したい。

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule, when a particle can be omitted, that’s when the meaning is clear without it. Although they are more liberally omitted in spoken language than in written language, some particles may be omitted under special circumstances even in written language, such as when they are used with どこか or 何か, as you say. What’s important to note here is that the same basic rule still applies and a particle can be omitted only when the meaning is clear without it.

When どこか is used with a verb that describes a movement from one place to another, most typically 行く, it is obvious that it is meant for どこかへ or どこかに. Therefore, へ or に can be safely omitted in this case. The reason へ seems always optional when に is not is because へ is used only with this kind of verb, or a verb of motion, whereas に has many more functions.

You might think に could be safely omitted when どこかに is used with a verb of presence or existence, such as ある and いる. However, grammar simply doesn’t permit that in written language. I guess the location (に) is considered less strongly associated with such a verb than the subject is. In fact, when 何か is used with a similar verb, が can be omitted.

When 何か is used with a verb that takes a direct object, such as する, it is by default understood as meaning 何かを even if を is omitted. This could be understood as the direct object is the most strongly associated with the verb, and therefore, を is considered the *least necessary* to understand the meaning of the sentence (because the verb itself takes care of it). Other grammatical elements, including the subject (が), the indirect object or target (に), the setting or place of action (で), the means (で), the companion (と), etc., are less strongly associated with the verb, and therefore, the meaning of the sentence would be less clear from the verb alone, if the particles were omitted. In fact, even in spoken language, these particles, with the exception of が, are usually not omitted.

When 何か is used with a verb that doesn’t take a direct object, it is understood as meaning 何かが even if が is omitted. The case of ある or いる, explained above, is just one such example.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the awnser. So, with「~ために、~」or「~とたんに、~」, に particle can be omitted, because the meaning is clear without it too ?